# Convert azure cli script to azure powershell CLI function

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

Because `Azure-CLI doesn't support runbook, function, logics`, only azure powershell can do it.
So if I'd like to upload my Azure CLI script to azure, I only have to convert azure cli to azure powershell..

Is there any cli function can convert azure cli script to azure powershell? e.g :
input `somefunction convert-cli-to-powershell 'az group list'`
oupout : `Get-AzManagementGroup`

input : `somefunction convert-cli-to-powershell 'az group show --resource-group system'`
oupout : `Get-AzManagementGroup -GroupName system`

It's a heavy job when script is large..

**What I've tried :**
Right now, I convert cli to powershell with my hands one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that tool doesn't exist. You can only do it manually.

Comment: Thanks, if there no one do it, I think I could try to do a little tool, replace mapping name .

Comment: @Wei ,That would be wonderful for a lot of people, good luck with the tool~

Comment: @Wei That will become messy because you would also have to do parameter mapping, which Azure Powershell and Azure CLI do very differently.

Comment: @RoadRunner yes, It's messy, I create a issue to ms azure [Convert azure cli script to azure powershell · Issue #13257 · Azure/azure-powershell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13257)

Comment: @Wei Yeah saw that. I think it will be quicker to just convert the CLI script to powershell manually. You can also run CLI commands in powershell, if you do not find the equivalent powershell command.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found any resource to do it =/

You can convert your script based on the resources.

Ex:
pwsh: Get-AzVm
az cli: az VM show

It will be a little bit hard, but I can help you too =D